# Set default value of Cobra flag with Viper

Tags: go, go-cobra, viper-go

I'm working on a Cobra-based app in Go and for one of my commands I'm defining a flag like this:

```go
func init() {
    myCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&project, "project", "p", "defaultProject", "Project name")
}
```

I also have a Viper set up in my root command that reads some configuration from a file. Is there a way to set the default value of the flag with Viper? I've tried this:

```go
func init() {
    myCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&project, "project", "p", viper.GetString("project"), "Project name")
}
```

But it seems this is not the way, as I'm getting an empty string if I omit the flag when calling the command. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you use the Viper `SetDefault` method? (https://github.com/spf13/viper/blob/8c894384998e656900b125e674b8c20dbf87cc06/viper.go#L1372-L1375)

Comment: I can, but that's not the case here. I want my flag value to fallback to my config value if flag is omitted and when I call my command with the `--help` flag  I want to see my config value in the end of the usage string where it says (default "....")

Answer (score 0):

Functions init() are called BEFORE calls to other functions, so yours init() is most likely called before the viper was read.

try somthing

```golang
func init() {
    loadViperConfig()
    myCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&project, "project", "p", viper.GetString("project"), "Project name")
}
```